# Why can't a process change the process group ID of one of its children after that child has called one of the exec functions?

Tags: process, process-groups

From APUE:

> A process  can  set  the  process  group  ID  of  only  itself  or  any  of  its  children.
>   Furthermore, it can’t change the process group ID of one of its children after that child
>   has called one of the exec functions.

Why can't it "change the process group ID of one of its children after that child has called one of the exec functions"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the "official" reason but I would guess that the idea is that a process shall not have to expect that its PGID is suddenly changed.

So this is allowed after a fork so that shell pipelines can be set up but after the `execve()` the new binary find a certain state, and this shall be permanent (until the new binary decides to change it).